# How to fix when BackdropScaffold frontLayer's elements doesn't appear?

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart

Sorry for the bad title:(!
My app *should* show in the home screen cards and FloatingActionButton, I've created the cards in separate file, so I'm forwarding the data to it, also to store my data I'm using sqlite which I'm new to it..
the FloatingActionButton should appear when I run the application, and I need it to add new cards. I know that the database is empty now, but why the FloatingActionButton is not appearing?

when running it it looks like this. [image]

I had followed a tutorial in the part when using the sqlite, and this is a part of my homeScreen code :

```
frontLayer: FutureBuilder<List<Reminder>>(
      future: _reminders,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          _currentReminders = snapshot.data!;
          return ListView(children: [
            ...snapshot.data!.map<Widget>((reminder) {
              return ReminderCard(
                  name: reminder.name, details: reminder.details);
            }).followedBy([
              Scaffold(
                backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
                floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  child: Icon(Icons.add),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              )
            ]).toList(),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            ),
            Scaffold(
              floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  child: Icon(Icons.add),
                  onPressed: () {}
```

this is the full code if I didn't paste the right part of my code: https://github.com/RarLasebai/reminder3/blob/main/lib/ui/Screens/homeScreen.dart

Comment: i have seen the code , have u changed it   ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have cloned your project and did a little changes on the `HomeScreen`
here is how u should do it

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:backdrop/backdrop.dart';
import 'package:untitled/helper.dart';
import 'package:untitled/models/reminder.dart';
import 'package:untitled/ui/widgets/ReminderCard.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController detailsController = TextEditingController();
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
late ReminderCard card;
RHelper helper = RHelper();
late Future<List<Reminder>> _reminders;
late List<Reminder> _currentReminders;
//-------------------------Functions----------------

bool status = true;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
helper.initializeDatabase().then((value) => {print("------------donne?")});
_loadReminders();
}

void _loadReminders() {
_reminders = helper.getReminders();
if (mounted) setState(() {});
}

//Screen and appBar frontend
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return BackdropScaffold(
backgroundColor: Colors.white,
appBar: BackdropAppBar(
centerTitle: true,
title: (Text(
'قائمة التذكيرات',
style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,
)),
),
headerHeight: 110.0,
frontLayer: FutureBuilder<List<Reminder>>(
future: _reminders,
builder: (context, snapshot) {
if (snapshot.hasData) {
_currentReminders = snapshot.data!;
return ListView(children: [
Column(
children: _currentReminders.map<Widget>((reminder) {
return ReminderCard(
name: reminder.name, details: reminder.details);
}).toList(),
),
Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
),

]);
}
return Center(child: Text("Loading>>.."));
},
),
backLayer: BackdropNavigationBackLayer(
items: [
ListTile(
leading: ImageIcon(AssetImage('icons/to-do-list.png')),
title: Align(
alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
child: Text("التذكيرات",
style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2)),
onTap: () {
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('home');
}),
Divider(),
ListTile(
leading: ImageIcon(AssetImage('icons/athkar.png')),
title: Align(
alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
child: Text("الأذكار",
style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2)),
onTap: () {
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('athkar');
}),
Divider(),
ListTile(
leading: ImageIcon(AssetImage('icons/mosque.png')),
title: Align(
alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
child: Text("مواقيت الصلاة",
style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2)),
onTap: () {
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('adhan');
},
),
Divider(),
ListTile(
leading: ImageIcon(AssetImage('icons/Tasbeeh.png')),
title: Align(
alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
child: Text("تسبيح",
style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2)),
onTap: () {
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('tasbeeh');
},
),
Divider(),
ListTile(
leading: ImageIcon(AssetImage('icons/quran.png')),
title: Align(
alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
child: Text("مصحف",
style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2)),
onTap: () {
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('moshaf');
},
),
Divider(),
ListTile(
leading: ImageIcon(AssetImage('icons/tadabur.png')),
title: Align(
alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
child: Text("وقفات تدبرية ",
style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2)),
onTap: () {
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('tadabur');
}),
Divider(),
ListTile(
leading: ImageIcon(AssetImage('icons/information.png')),
title: Align(
alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
child: Text("تواصل معنا",
style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2)),
onTap: () {
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('contact');
})
],
),
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
child: Icon(Icons.add),
onPressed: () {
showModalBottomSheet(
useRootNavigator: true,
context: context,
clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
top: Radius.circular(24),
),
),
builder: (context) {
return StatefulBuilder(
builder: (context, setModalState) {
return Container(
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
child: Form(
key: _formKey,
child: Column(
children: [
TextFormField(
validator: (String? value) {
if (value!.isEmpty)
return 'Please enter name';
},
controller: detailsController,
style: TextStyle(
color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15.0),
decoration: InputDecoration(
errorStyle: TextStyle(
color: Colors.red, fontSize: 15.0),
labelText: 'اسم التذكير',
labelStyle: TextStyle(
color: Colors.black,
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
fontSize: 15.0,
),
border: OutlineInputBorder(
borderRadius:
BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
),
),
SizedBox(
height: 10,
),
TextFormField(
controller: nameController,
style: TextStyle(
color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15.0),
decoration: InputDecoration(
labelText: 'التفاصيل',
labelStyle: TextStyle(
color: Colors.black,
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
fontSize: 15.0,
),
border: OutlineInputBorder(
borderRadius:
BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
),
),
SizedBox(
height: 10,
),
ElevatedButton(
onPressed: () {
setState(() {
if (_formKey.currentState!
.validate()) {
_save();
Navigator.pop(context);
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
content: Text(
'تم حفظ التذكير')));
}
});
},
child: Text('حفظ'),
)
],
),
),
);
});
},
);
})
);
}

void _save() {
var _reminder = Reminder(
name: nameController.text, details: detailsController.text, save: 0);
helper.insertReminder(_reminder);
_loadReminders();
}
}
```

and for a athkar project i really suggest that you use `provider` or `riverpod` , or any kind of state management

Comment: Thank you for answering sir! I copied the edited part of code you did it and run the application but I still couldn't find the floating action button, does it worked for you?

Comment: I'm trying to make a reminders app, and other screens are additional. Thank you, Im so happy that you replied to my question.

Comment: The code the i provided u worked for me , and the `floatingbutton` as i recall pops up a dialog from bottom to make a new reminder

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w_Jdd8NWR6_XwDztZUOu9FDV7PiduZCp/view?usp=sharing

Comment: that's right, why it's not working for me?

Comment: I copied the full code you provided and reinstall the app but it's not working.

Comment: Give me 2 hours qnd ill check it ok ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233997/discussion-between-fahmi-sawalha-and-abrar-lasebai).

Comment: Okay, Thank you!